# Mapping through object entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck trying to map through an object containing arrays. I'm using react and want to create a button displaying a chord and its grade according to this object below:

```
{
"tonic": "C",
"grades": [
    "I",
    "II",
    "III",
    "IV",
    "V",
    "VI",
    "VII"
],
"intervals": [
    "1P",
    "2M",
    "3M",
    "4P",
    "5P",
    "6M",
    "7M"
],
"scale": [
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "A",
    "B"
],
"chords": [
    "Cmaj7",
    "Dm7",
    "Em7",
    "Fmaj7",
    "G7",
    "Am7",
    "Bm7b5"
],
"chordsHarmonicFunction": [
    "T",
    "SD",
    "T",
    "SD",
    "D",
    "T",
    "D"
],
"chordScales": [
    "C major",
    "D dorian",
    "E phrygian",
    "F lydian",
    "G mixolydian",
    "A minor",
    "B locrian"
],
"type": "major",
"minorRelative": "A",
"alteration": 0,
"keySignature": "",
"secondaryDominants": [
    "",
    "A7",
    "B7",
    "C7",
    "D7",
    "E7",
    ""
],
"secondaryDominantsMinorRelative": [
    "",
    "Em7b5",
    "F#m7",
    "Gm7",
    "Am7",
    "Bm7b5",
    ""
],
"substituteDominants": [
    "",
    "Eb7",
    "F7",
    "Gb7",
    "Ab7",
    "Bb7",
    ""
],
"substituteDominantsMinorRelative": [
    "",
    "Em7",
    "Cm7",
    "Dbm7",
    "Am7",
    "Fm7",
    ""
]
```

}

I looked up similar issues and followed this:
[Mapping through Object Data into React Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886296/mapping-through-object-data-into-react-components#new-answer?newreg=81ba9ee00fce46d1b9464635287f8d46)

leading me to the following code:

```
 {Object.entries(keyChords).map(([key, value], i) => (
    <button key={i}>{value}</button>
  ))}
```

Returning value gives me all the values available.
But at this point, I would expect that I could access the chords array like {value.chords} but that doesn't work.
How can I access the individual arrays so that I could map through the chords and grades array to create a button that displays that data?

Comment: What do you want to do with the values?

Comment: I need a way to target keys like chords and grades and map through the values in order to create a button for each chord.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, values]) => {
  // you now have access to values with Array type
  if (values instanceof Array) {
    values.forEach((value) => {
      // log each value of array
      // each value of grades, intervals, etc
      console.log(value)
    })
  }
})
```

give this a try. Note that this is JS way, but you can use the same concept to apply it with React.

[Edited]

I just wrote a React version for you :)

```
<div className="App">
  {Object.entries(data).map(([key, values]) => (
    <>
    {values instanceof Array && values.map((value) => (
      <>
      {value && <button key={value}>{value}</button>}
      </>
    ))}
  </>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mapping-through-object-entries-roprt7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is close to a solution, I'm just struggling to target only the chords array in the data (and grades). At this point all values are being returned as a button. How do I target in the button? So that I'd have a button with one chord and one grade, something like: `<button> {data.chords} {data.grades}</button>`

Comment: i am not sure if i understand it right but i updated the code for you. Revisit the link.

Comment: other than than you can update it based on your requirements.